# How to call or update from a function?

Tags: vb.net

I have a asp.net VB code to insert draft/saved messages into a a new table created for draft messages database. I want to check if the the record exists before it is saved. So I have made a function (selecting the unique record ). Now how do I call this function and update the values, it is showing me the error 'Conversion from string "srno" to type 'Integer' is not valid."

Comment: It would be helpful to see the actual code, otherwise we'd all just be guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error

> Conversion from string "srno" to type
>   'Integer' is not valid.

probably means that a function expects an Integer as a parameter but you send it a string (srno). Either refactor your method to accept a string instead, or send it an Integer instead of a string.